# Package Conflicts in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

When I load tidyverse [or type `tidyverse_conflicts()`] a warning message appears telling me there is a conflict between two functions `dplyr::filter()` and `dplyr::lag()`. How can we avoid such conflict? Thanks for your response! Here is a snapshot:

[image: tidyverse conflicts]

Comment: There are multiple ways, one is when you load the package use `exclude` `library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))` or create a object name i.e. `dplyrlag <- dplyr::lag` and then use the function created or another option is to load the package with the function you want to use after the package having the same function, thus it overrides the function from other package

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid a conflict? Is there a particular error you are trying to work around? The conflict happens because dplyr decided to name some of its function the same as some base R function. That will not be changing anytime soon.

Answer (score 7):

When we load `tidyverse` a messege says "Use the conflicted package to force all conflicts to become errors".

Therefore all you have to do is:

```
library(conflicted)  

library(tidyverse)
conflict_prefer("filter", "dplyr")
conflict_prefer("lag", "dplyr")
```

But if you prefer, you can just write your code using the *package::funcion()* format, for exemple: `dplyr::filter()` and `dplyr::lag()`

Answer (score 0):

That message means that from that moment:

- if you use `filter()`, the `filter()` from `dplyr` will be used, rather than the `filter()` from base R (`stats`);
- similarly for `lag()`.

(There isn't any conflict between `dplyr::filter()` and `dplyr::lag()`.)

This is usually not an issue - the vast majority of code will work just fine.

If for any reason you want to use the base R version of either of these two functions, you can simply call them explicitly: `stats::filter(...)` or `stats::lag(...)`