Conflicts in installing tidyverse
✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()  
✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()  
ℹ Use the conflicted package to force all conflicts to become errors

I got this error message while loading the "tidyverse" package.
What is the step i can do to solve the problem?
Other chunks after this doesn't work.

Conflicts are normal and those 2 are expected.  Can you be more specific regarding "Other chunks after this doesn't work" ? (code and errors / warnings)

Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73336628/package-conflicts-in-r

This message is just a warning, indicating that the dplyr package has functions (filter and lag) that have the same names as functions in the stats package, which is loaded by default in R. By default, the dplyr versions of these functions will be used when you call filter() or lag().
Here’s how to address this and ensure your code works smoothly:

Specify the Package: If you want to explicitly use the stats versions of filter or lag, you can prefix the function with the package name:

For stats::filter() or stats::lag(), use stats::filter() and stats::lag() explicitly in your code when you need those versions.


Use conflicted Package (Optional): If you want to prevent all conflicts from happening, you can use the conflicted package, which will throw an error whenever there’s ambiguity about which function to use. Install and load conflicted, then re-run your code:
install.packages("conflicted")
library(conflicted)
library(tidyverse)

This will force you to specify which filter or lag function you intend to use.

Restart R Session: Sometimes R sessions can become cluttered with packages, leading to unexpected behavior. Restarting the R session and re-running the code may resolve errors in other chunks. You can restart by selecting "Session" > "Restart R" in RStudio.


