Why does the following code cause an import conflict?
library(stats, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))
library(tidyverse)

causes
── Attaching core tidyverse packages ──────────────────────── tidyverse 2.0.0 ──
✔ dplyr     1.1.4     ✔ readr     2.1.5
✔ forcats   1.0.0     ✔ stringr   1.5.1
✔ ggplot2   3.5.1     ✔ tibble    3.2.1
✔ lubridate 1.9.3     ✔ tidyr     1.3.1
✔ purrr     1.0.2     
── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
ℹ Use the conflicted package to force all conflicts to become errors

why is the exclude argument not doing the trick?

stats is automatically attached when R starts, so library(stats, exclude = c("filter", "lag")) doesn't actually do anything. All of the functions from stats are already loaded.

@gabagool Very strange that dplyr masks a base-library function! Is there a recommended way to get rid of the warning?

Do you have a reason to get rid of the warning? I think general opinion (including mine) is you want to keep warnings. If you decide to get rid of them, perhaps library(dplyr, warn.conflicts=FALSE) or one of the other options mentioned here

Sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73336628/package-conflicts-in-r (among others)

@gabagool When tidying code for release, I try to address the root cause of every warning. In this case I managed it by importing dplyr instead of tidyverse and excluding the colliding functions.
